# Obtaining density from a sequence of moments?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose moments of my distribution are $1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429,\ldots$ , ie [Catalan numbers](https://oeis.org/A000108)

These correspond to Marchenko-Pastur density, ie for  for $x\in [0,4]$
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}}{2 \pi  x}$$

How could I obtain the density above from this sequence of moments?

Comment: This sounds like it can be obtained by applying [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform), the inversion formula.

Comment: Ah, yes. See [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/SIXDENIERS/Catalan.pdf).